# Left/Right Join with reference to another table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to access three tables to have something like this:

```
+------+------+------+
| ITEM |  PCS |  CSS |
+------+------+------+
| 1099 |    2 |   11 |
| 1098 |    2 |    2 | 
| 1097 |    2 |    1 | 
| 1096 | NULL | NULL | 
| 1095 | NULL | NULL | 
| 1094 | NULL | NULL |  
| 1093 | NULL | NULL | 
| 1092 | NULL | NULL | 
+------+------+------+
```

But, all I get is this:

```
+------+------+------+
| ITEM |  PCS |  CSS |
+------+------+------+
| 1099 |    2 |   11 |
| 1098 |    2 |    2 | 
| 1097 |    2 |    1 | 
+------+------+------+
```

//I am a little bit confused with my query so here is a breakdown of what I'm trying to do instead:

```
SELECT CODE
FROM SET2
WHERE MO = MONTH(SYSDATE())
AND YR = YEAR(SYSDATE())

//and then:

SELECT ITEM, PCS, CSS
FROM SET3
WHERE S3.CODE=S2.CODE

//then:

SELECT ITEM
FROM SET1
WHERE S1.ITEM=S3.ITEM
```

My tables

SET1

```
+------+
| ITEM |
+------+
| 1099 |
| 1098 | 
| 1097 | 
| 1096 | 
| 1095 | 
| 1094 | 
| 1093 | 
| 1092 | 
+------+
```

SET2

```
+------+-----+------+
|   YR |  MO | CODE |
+------+-----+------+
| 2013 |   1 |    1 | 
| 2013 |   2 |    2 | 
+------+-----+------+
```

SET3

```
+------+-----+------+------+
|  PCS | CSS | CODE | ITEM |
+------+-----+------+------+
|    2 |  11 |    1 | 1099 |
|    2 |   2 |    1 | 1098 | 
|    2 |   1 |    1 | 1097 | 
+------+-----+------+------+
```

Comment: You're right, thank you for pointing that out. 1099, 1098, 1097 are values for ITEM and are not years

Comment: Then @Jack answer below should give you that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use left joins for that to work:

```
SELECT SET1.ITEM, PCS, CSS
FROM SET1
LEFT JOIN SET3 ON SET3.ITEM = SET1.ITEM
LEFT JOIN SET2 ON SET2.CODE = SET3.CODE 
    AND SET2.MO = MONTH(SYSDATE()) 
    AND SET2.YR = YEAR(SYSDATE())
```